# Existence of a geodesic with velocity vanishing somewhere

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Actually, I'd like to understand the following proposition that guarantees the existence of a geodesic.

> **Corollary 4.28.** *Let $M$ be a smooth manifold and let $\nabla$ be a connection in $TM$. For each $p\in M$ and $v\in T_p M$, there is a unique maximal geodesic $\gamma:I\to M$ with $\gamma(0)=p$ and $\gamma'(0)=v$, defined on some open interval $I$ containing $0$.*

I'm kind of wondering if this corollary works when $v$ happens to be the zero vector. May I symbolize this case as a physical object that doesn't move with time? I feel awkward about a curve consisting of a single point.

Thank you for your time.

**Reference.** Lee, John M., *Introduction to Riemannian manifolds*

Comment: Just to respond to your title: Every geodesic has constant speed. So if its velocity vanishes somewhere, it vanishes everywhere.

Comment: @TedShifrin Yeah, you are right. A geodesic is a smooth curve without acceleration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The corollary works fine when $v = 0$. Then the unique maximal geodesic would simply be the constant curve $\gamma(t) = p$ for all $t\in\mathbb R$. It is true that $\gamma$ is a somewhat "degenerate" curve, but mathematically it is a perfectly valid one. There are other examples of curves that may elicit "awkward" feelings, such as space-filling curves, i.e., $\gamma(I)$ being equal to an open subset of $M$, or even all of $M$ (such a $\gamma$ exists, but is not differentiable, and is certainly not a geodesic), but ultimately, they are an equally valid part of the flora/fauna of mathematical objects.